# How to animate a View with Translate Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have one ImageView in my application which can be situated anywhere on screen

On touch I want to move this view at the center of the Screen. I tried this functionality with Translate Animation and its RELATIVE_TO_PARENT functionality as follows

```
TranslateAnimation translateAnimation1 = new TranslateAnimation(
      TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0.0f,
      TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0.5f,
      TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0.0f,
      TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0.5f);
```

but ImageView moves 50% (of the screen) down from its current position.

Is there any way to move this view to the center of the screen regardless of its current position?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In order to move a View anywhere on the screen, I would recommend placing it in a full screen layout. By doing so, you won't have to worry about clippings or relative coordinates.

You can try this sample code:

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/rootLayout">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MOVE" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:layout_marginLeft="60dip" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginBottom="100dip"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:clipChildren="false" android:clipToPadding="false">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:layout_marginLeft="60dip" android:layout_marginTop="150dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Your activity**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ((Button) findViewById( R.id.btn1 )).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.img1 );              
            moveViewToScreenCenter( img );
            img = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.img2 );
            moveViewToScreenCenter( img );
            img = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.img3 );                
            moveViewToScreenCenter( img );
            img = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.img4 );
            moveViewToScreenCenter( img );
        }
    });
}

private void moveViewToScreenCenter( View view )
{
    RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.rootLayout );
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );
    int statusBarOffset = dm.heightPixels - root.getMeasuredHeight();

    int originalPos[] = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos );

    int xDest = dm.widthPixels/2;
    xDest -= (view.getMeasuredWidth()/2);
    int yDest = dm.heightPixels/2 - (view.getMeasuredHeight()/2) - statusBarOffset;

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDest - originalPos[0] , 0, yDest - originalPos[1] );
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setFillAfter( true );
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

The method `moveViewToScreenCenter` gets the View's absolute coordinates and calculates how much distance has to move from its current position to reach the center of the screen. The `statusBarOffset` variable measures the status bar height.

I hope you can keep going with this example. Remember that after the animation your view's position is still the initial one. If you tap the MOVE button again and again the same movement will repeat. If you want to change your view's position do it after the animation is finished.

Comment: I used this moveViewToScreenCenter but changed it to move the view to top right of screen. It works when launched from a button like in your example, but when launching moveViewToScreenCenter from onCreate, the view goes a totally other way. It seems that the originalPos is always [0,0] for a View in onCreate. What gives?

Comment: In `onCreate` views dimensions are 0 because the the Activity is not visible to the user yet. Try placing the call in the `onWindowFocusChanged` method.

Comment: It doesn't woke for me, my view moves to down !