# Android TranslateAnimation to Center

Tags: java, android, android-animation, translate-animation

I need to apply a translation animation to an ImageView, this ImageView is positioned at certain place and i need to animate it to the center of the screen. Here is my translate xml code, but it doesn't animate the ImageView to the center.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="50%p"
        android:toYDelta="50%p" />
</set>
```

This is the XML where the ImageView is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/WelcomeLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/welcome_background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/welcome_innovaLogo"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/welcome_innovaLogoString"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/innova_logo" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/welcome_innovaInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/welcome_innovaLogo"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/welcome_innovaLogo"
    android:text="@string/welcome_innovaInfoString"
    android:textColor="#9acd32"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/welcome_innovaHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/welcome_innovaInfo"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="@string/welcome_innovaHeaderString"
    android:textColor="#9acd32"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/welcome_commandsListView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_innovaLogo"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/welcome_loadingLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_large" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Loading Data..."
        android:textColor="@color/green_color"
        android:textSize="19sp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<!--
     <fragment
    android:id="@+id/welcome_facebookFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_innovaLogo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/welcome_commandsListView"
    class="innovaEgypt.com.Welcome.FacebookFragment" >
</fragment>
-->
```

Comment: "but it doesn't animate the ImageView to the center." what does it do instead?

Comment: It's animated also but not to the center!

Comment: Please, post the layout xml file where the ImageView is.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10276251/871102) question. I gave a similar answer but the animation is not from an xml but from code. Hope it helps.

---

EDIT:

Your problem is that the animation doesn't take into account the image dimensions. The animation is centering the origin coordinate of your `ImageView`.

I still suggest my solution.

I tried the code in the answer that I linked and it works. Just copy this function:

```
private void moveViewToScreenCenter( View view )
{
    RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.WelcomeLayout );
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );
    int statusBarOffset = dm.heightPixels - root.getMeasuredHeight();

    int originalPos[] = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos );

    int xDest = dm.widthPixels/2;
    xDest -= (view.getMeasuredWidth()/2);
    int yDest = dm.heightPixels/2 - (view.getMeasuredHeight()/2) - statusBarOffset;

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDest - originalPos[0] , 0, yDest - originalPos[1] );
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setFillAfter( true );
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

and call it passing your view as the parameter:

```
    ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.welcome_innovaLogo );
    moveViewToScreenCenter(img1);
```

If your image still disappear, maybe is because it is behind your other widgets, like the `ListView`. If that is the case, reestructure your xml layout definig the `ImageView` at the end, just after the `Listview` (just cut and paste the `ImageView`).

Comment: It didn't work :(, whenver the animation is started the ImageView disappears.

Answer (score 3):

For future updates...

Apply view property animation to move position of widget. Image view in this case

```
int layoutWidth = parentLayout.getWidth();

layoutWidth = ((int) layoutWidth / 2) - (imageView.getWidth()) ;

Log.d(TAG, " position - " + layoutWidth);

imageView.animate()
    .translationX(-layoutWidth)
    .translationY(0)
    .setDuration(500)
    .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
    .start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding delay to this code.

```
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            moveViewToScreenCenter( view );
                        }
                    }, 
                1000);
```