# getLocationOnScreen() in onCreate() just returns zeroes

Tags: android

Calling getLocationOnScreen() on an ImageView (or other View) in a response to a button click gives correct values.

But when calling getLocationOnScreen() from Activity::onCreate(), I only get [0, 0]. How can I fix this?

Is onCreate() too early for all calculations to be done? Is there a later better place to hook to start animations?

Comment: what are your goal?to create an starting point for an animation??

Comment: Using the code in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10542153/129202 as an example. It moves views to center of screen with push of a button. If the same cycle is caused already in onCreate, it doesn't work as view.getLocationOnScreen() returns empty values.

Comment: @NikoAdrianusYuwono yeah actually  I have same question. I am trying to animate my ProgressBar when it scroll my RecyclerView. I want it to animate when its start sowing till the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's too early to check for `getLocationOnScreen()` in `onCreate()`. The better place is at view level (if you are using custom views), is at `onLayout()`. Only here, the view's size and position are calculated. In case, you aren't creating custom views, you could obtain it in activity level at `onWindowFocusChanged()` (with the activity having the focus).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the same answer `onWindowFocusChanged()` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6560726/129202
I'd say the reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[]) is a bit too hush hush on these common pitfalls that a lot of people seem to have.