# Why does location on screen always return 0?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-screen

I want to know the position of an image view but its always returns `0` neither the `x` coordinate or `y` coordinate. Here is my code

```
    ImageView credits = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.credits);
    int[] coor = {0,0};
    credits.getLocationOnScreen(coor);
    x = coor[0];
    y = coor[1];
```

I already use many method such as `getTop()`, etc. but still its return 0.

Anyone know why? I'm new to android so I really appreciate to any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing that in the onCreate method ?

If yes, it's too early to check for getLocationOnScreen() in onCreate()

Solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13244091/5392383

Comment: yep i got it. i put it in onCreate() before. thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this code inside `onCreate()` method?

After quick search I found [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243914/getlocationonscreen-in-oncreate-just-returns-zeroes).

shortly, it sayd `onCreate()` is too early to use `getLocationOnScreen`, you should use it in side the method `onWindowFocusChanged()` when your `Activity` gains focus.

Answer (score 0):

```
  credits.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           int[] coor = {0,0};
           credits.getLocationOnScreen(coor);
           x = coor[0];
           y = coor[1]; 
        }
    })
```

try like this

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this

```
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ImageView credits = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.credits);
        int[] coor = {0,0};
        credits.getLocationOnScreen(coor);
        x = coor[0];
        y = coor[1];
    }
```