# Translate animation in android

Tags: android, translate-animation

I am new in android. I want to use the translate animation in android. I want that the red rounded image comes from center of the layout. It comes . But i want that the red rounded image comes back from the center image which color is green.

I am not able to attach image because my reputation below 15.

Comment: Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276251/how-to-animate-a-view-with-translate-animation-in-android. It might help you.

Comment: Please elaborate your question properly..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take 2 images - red and green.
You will have to use `AnimationListners` for that and maintain boolean variable to check whether you want to animate red color or green color.

Comment: i am able to translate image from 1 loc to another loc. But the problem is that 2nd image going from up of image 1. i want that 2nd image go bellow from image 1.

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting what you are trying to do. Post some code.

Comment: OK thanks allot when i got 15 reputation then i post this question again with image

Comment: @zanky, can you help me with this translate animation, I have been trying to get this thing to run, Apparently I am not able to get location for any imageview in my code, Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

you need to structure you layout with this images. 2image must be under 1 image on your layout.