# How to change position of imageview in android?

Tags: android, android-wifi, indoor-positioning-system

I am creating an indoor navigation app. I am using RSSI value of wifi for navigation. The problem is: How can I move the imageview with red spot when the value of RSSI changes?

My work so far:

[image: Indoor navigation so far]

```
ImageView iv1; //map image
ImageView iv2; //red spot
TextView tv1;

   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.registerReceiver(this.myRssiChangeReceiver, 
            new IntentFilter(WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION));

    iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    }

    private BroadcastReceiver myRssiChangeReceiver 
= new BroadcastReceiver(){

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 int newRssi = arg1.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NEW_RSSI, 0);
 //result.setText(String.valueOf(newRssi));
 tv1.setText(String.valueOf(newRssi));
     }};
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.smshah.indoormap.MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/uit_floor_plan" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/loc_ptr" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Comment: nice picture, what about some code?

Comment: @lelloman code added upon your request

Comment: Could you also include the portion of activity_main.xml responsible for displaying the map and dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at examples for animation like [this](http://androidsurya.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-image-animation-example.html).  I think the [LinearInterpolator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) would be the way to go if you could tie it to your location change event and update the from - to coordinates.

**EDIT:** Look into this [TranslateAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276251/how-to-animate-a-view-with-translate-animation-in-android) sample.  That may be more helpful to you.

Comment: This is a good answer. You'll also want to switch from RelativeLayout to FrameLayout and use android:layout_gravity="left|top" to position your TextView.