# change background with animation when user clicks on it

Tags: android, animation, layout, dynamic, textview

I used one LinearLayout in my activity for changing two views. Here, i used two textviews. When user clicks on linear layout i change views as per my requirnments. xml file is here,

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/customswitchselector"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearTab"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:showText="true"
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_switch1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#272351"
                style="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_switch_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                style="bold"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

[image: first image when not clicked][image: second image after click]

These two images show my two conditions. I have done enough to change this. Now i want to do animation while i am changing background for textviews on layout clicks. I have checked transitiondrawable example but it not helpful to me.

**customswitchselector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**custom_track.xml** This is used for textview with blue background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:useLevel="false"
    android:visible="true">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#292850"
        android:startColor="#292850" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="30dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-in-android?rq=1

Comment: Why don't you use Translate Animation ? I think it will be more suitable for your feature. Reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276251/how-to-animate-a-view-with-translate-animation-in-android

Comment: Here i am using custom_track drawable for look like blue background with round corner and after click event i change background with Color.TRANSPARENT. I already mention Mr. Durgesh transition animation not works in my work. I am not moving my view from one place to another place that's why i don't use translate animation.

Comment: did u try adding <<<android:animateLayoutChanges="true">>> to your parent linear layout.

Comment: Post also `@drawable/customswitchselector`.

Comment: @IsmailIqbal yes i have tried that

Comment: It will be better to use custom radio button in this scenario this Example:http://www.limbaniandroid.com/2014/05/custom-radio-buttons-example-in-android.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility would be to set the white drawable as background of a `FrameLayout` and add a `View` for the blue oval and two `TextViews` for the titles to it.

To still acchieve that the views takes exactly the half of the container you could use `PercenFrameLayout` (read more about it [in the official docu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html)). To use it you need to add this dependency to your `build.gradle`: `compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.2.0'`

After creating the layout you just animate the gravity of the blue oval from left to right or the other way round.

So your layout would look like this:

```
<PercentFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@drawable/white_oval"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- blue oval -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/blue_oval"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_oval"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:transformPivotX="0dp" />

    <!--2 textviews-->
    <TextView
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="left"
        android:gravity="start"/>

    <TextView
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="right"
        android:gravity="end"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then in your code animate the gravity change of the blue oval like this:

```
private void animateGravity(int toGravity) {
    LayoutTransition layoutTransition = container.getLayoutTransition();
    layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    layoutTransition.setDuration(YOUR_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    layoutTransition.setInterpolator(LayoutTransition.CHANGING, new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) blueOvalView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.gravity = toGravity;
    blueOvalView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your time. I will try that

Comment: I think there must be two TextViews

Comment: why are you thinking about 2 textviews?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the background in the container - I just added this line: `android:background="@drawable/white_oval"`

Comment: oh sorry you are right - wait a second I'll update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139245/discussion-between-lalit-jadav-and-katharina).