# Translate Animation in Android - Starts in centre of Screen

Tags: android, xml, animation, position, translate

I have an `Imageview` in a `RelativeLayout`. It should start from the centre of the screen (parent) and than goes to a specific point. Actual i work with **xml**. 
Any Solutions?

My Animation XML-

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="false">

  <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:pivotX="0%p"
        android:pivotY="0%p"/>

  <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:fromXScale="432px"
      android:toXScale="100%"
      android:fromYScale="450px"
      android:toYScale="100%"
      android:duration="1000"
      android:pivotX="0%p"
      android:pivotY="0%p" />
</set>
```

I've tried it in `fromYDelta` and `fromXDelta` with `100%p, 50%p, 0%p, 100, 50, 0, 100%, 50% and 0%`. Nothing works!
Now im confused!
Thanks for your time and help

Edit:

[A picture to explain what the Animation should do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mszwr.png)

Comment: have you tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276251/how-to-animate-a-view-with-translate-animation-in-android?answertab=votes#tab-top ?

Comment: It's an element from the banner, which is top (32dp marginTop) and center. but the Image needs to be left in the Banner

Comment: Yeah i tried it but then i need to figure a way to put it back in the Banner

Answer (score 0):

Add this in anim folder:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:fromYDelta="50%p" 
    android:toXDelta="50%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" 
    android:duration="1000" 
    android:fillAfter="true" />
```

Implement this in code like :

```
translateAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.translate_anim);
imageView.startAnimation(translateAnim);
```

This will move image from centre to top.

Comment: Can i change this 
android:toXDelta="50%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" 
into 
android:toXDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="100%"

Comment: That totally depends on you purpose how you want to translate object over screen.

Comment: Tried it but the image dont starts in the center its more a little bit right and lower than center. it looks like it takes the left upper corner for center

Comment: may be there can be issue with you layout design.

Comment: Sry for my late answer, but i checked my design 2 times... For me everything seems ok. Do you have another option or suggestion?